# how to filter table by column in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filterrific

I am displaying a list of user in my table (no pagination). User contains id, name, age, status, location. I want to allow the list to be filtered by age or status. How do I do this in ruby rails ? I tried using [filterrific](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/)  but stuck since last two days [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719100/using-filterrific-gem-to-filter-table-by-column)

```
Id name age status location
1  xz    22  single  ca
2  yy    23  married ma
```

view

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>status</th>
      <th>location</th>
    </tr>
    <% items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.id %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.age %></td>
        <td><%= item.status %></td>
        <td><%= item.lcation %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

controller

```
 def index
    @items  = User.all
  end
```

Comment: What have you tried? The tutorial you posted is very straight forward about implementation

Comment: I followed that but I am not sure where I am going wrong. I get an error 'undefined method page'

Comment: this is what i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719100/using-filterrific-gem-to-filter-table-by-column

Answer (score 1):

I think, [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?autoplay=true) cast can help you perfect without any gems.